# Java Regular Expression with International Letters

Tags: java, regex, internationalization

Here's my current code:

```
return str.matches("^[A-Za-z\\-'. ]+");
```

I want it to include international letters.  How do I do that in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `international letters`?

Comment: Get an international keyboard?

Comment: Or a penfriend in another country :-)

Comment: Are you asking about localizing your application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you want is, to match all the *alphabetic* characters. Typically you would do that by using Posix `\p{Alpha}` expression, extended by the punctuation you want also to permit. As [Java Regular Expressions documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) says, it matches ASCII only.

However, what documentation does not say clearly is, you can make this class work with Unicode characters. To do just that you need to turn *Unicode character class* matching on.
You can do this in one of two ways:

1. By creating `Pattern` object passing the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` constant:
   `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[p{Alpha}\\-'. ]+", UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);`
2. By using `(?U)` embedded pattern flag:
   `str.matches("^(?U)[\\p{Alpha}\\-'. ]+");`

Prove of concept:

```
String[] test = {"Jean-Marie Le'Blanc", "Żółć", "Ὀδυσσεύς", "原田雅彦"};
for (String str : test) {
    System.out.print(str.matches("^(?U)[\\p{Alpha}\\-'. ]+") + " ");
}
```

The obvious result is:

> true true true true

If you think that all is correct, I have two additional points to make:

- 原田雅彦 (Masahiko Harada) is composed of [Ideographic characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideogram). In fact they are ***not*** the alphabetic characters,
- You want to match the dot (.) symbol. It's OK, but please consider matching [Ideographic fullstops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Full_stops_in_other_scripts) as well.

Comment: Just a small correction. In your first suggestion you forgot the 2 backslashes in front of the p.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to match alphanumeric characters other than the ASCII letters A-Z. You can do this with the `\p{IsAlphabetic}` Unicode character class:

```
return str.matches("^[\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\-'. ]+");
```

You'll find more Unicode character classes the [full documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

Replace the pattern with:

```
"^[\\p{L}\\-'. ]+"
```

`\p{L}` includes all unicode letters.

Answer (score 2):

Use the regex `\P{L}` to match any letters (national or international)

By adding `[\p{L}&&[^\p{IsLatin}]]`, you can match all letters that are not latin.

Especially for Greek, regex has `\p{InGreek}` to match Greek letters and `\P{InGreek}`(the difference is capital P) to match non Greek letters.

Answer (score 0):

The question cannot be answered completely unless you say what you mean by "international letters", but the general solution is to use named character classes, via the `\p{name}` syntax.  There are many named character classes.  Some are defined by the regex language, and others by the Unicode standard.  Refer to the [Pattern javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a partial list, and to the relevant Unicode standard.