# Fast and neat check that a string only contains alphabet, regardless of character set?

Tags: java, validation, character-encoding

Sorry, posted that too soon.

This is the real question:

I require a validation string, that validates a name only contains characters from real alphabets - can be any, unrestricted to one particular.

e.g. it may be Japanese, or Russian, or plain ASCII.

I've looked at [Java function to return if string contains illegal characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635391/java-function-to-return-if-string-contains-illegal-characters#14635454) which is pretty good, but only suitable for Latin languages.

I looked at [Validate a string contains only certain characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038426/validate-a-string-contains-only-certain-characters-in-java#20038995) which talks about `java.util.Scanner` but that wasn't designed for this purpose really.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636540/java-regular-expression-with-international-letters ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand no, very interesting. I was searching around the 'validation' theme although I think even with regex in the search terms but didn't see it.

Comment: Well, this answer provides a Regex that was used to return true with names from various alphabets. It seems to me that it answers exactly your need once you remove the . and \s from the regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "alphabet"? Any letter? (There many letters that aren't in official alphabets.) `String` contains codepoints from the Unicode character set. Java libraries don't know about every character set ever invented.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the problem. I mean alphabet = any letter that is in any alphabet. What do you mean by letters that aren't in official alphabets? I'm not too worried about unofficial alphabets, I'm more concerned with catching characters that are definitely for punctuation, printing or other purposes. With a couple of exceptions, e.g. `.`, `_` or `-`.

Comment: I think @JeremyGrand has the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42350563/2226988) then. [Language academies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_regulators) and others determine what letters are in a language's alphabet. For example, in English, the letters é, ö, æ, etc are not in the alphabet although they are used in English texts. In much of computing, which letters are in one or more alphabets is not important. Unicode designates certain characters as letters. That's what [\p{Alpha}](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) follows.

Comment: Great, apart from the fact that 原田 doesn't match using `Pattern.compile("^[p{Alnum}._\\-]+",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);` but I guess that is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662136/7573818, does the following solve your case ?

```
str.matches("^(?U)[\\p{Alpha}\\-']+")
```

Comment: Like I said in my other comment, I missed that one because I wasn't searching so heavily on "regex", mostly because one of the answers given in the first link I quoted said, quote "If you must do it character-by-character, regexp is probably not a good way to go" but that is unsubstantiated. There may well be no decent alternatives.

Comment: No, the comment "if you must do it character by character" was meant for the Regex pattern : if you have to precise every character in the pattern, it's not the right approach. But if you compiled this simple Regex, it would be the best way to do it. How can you validate a String other than checking every character ?